# poll() waits indefinitely although timeout is specified

Tags: c, server, client, polling, unix-socket

I'm writing a C client-server program, in which the client has to receive a large amount of data from the server. Since I want my client not to wait indefinitely on a `recv()` if something goes wrong with the server (e.g., it's stopped when data is being sent), I opted to use the `poll()` function as specified in the [linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html).

My code is something like the following:

```
while (...)
{
  struct pollfd fds;
  fds.fd = sock;
  fds.events = POLLIN;

retry:
  r = poll(&fds, 1, TIMEOUT*1000);
  if (r == -1 && errno == EINTR)
    goto retry;
  else if (r == -1)
    err_sys("poll() failed");
  else if (r == 0)
    err_sys("timeout expired");

  recv(...)
}
```

where `sock` is the file descriptor associated with the socket, `TIMEOUT` is set to 5 seconds and I specify `POLLIN` as the event since I'm interested in reading data.

**Problem**

According to man:

> The timeout argument specifies the number of milliseconds that poll()
>          should block waiting for a file descriptor to become ready.  The call
>          will block until either:
>
> ```
>    (1)  a file descriptor becomes ready;
>
>    (2)  the call is interrupted by a signal handler; or
>
>    (3)  the timeout expires.
> ```

However, the program blocks indefinitely on the `poll()` function even though the timeout expires (I used valgrind) as soon as I stop the server. I also tried to set the events to `POLLIN | POLLPRI` (in order to catch some exceptional conditions) but it didn't work. I read the documentation multiple times and I couldn't figure out what's causing this problem.

**Other info**

I'm using Xubuntu 18.04, gcc version 7.4.0, target x86_64

Comment: Run your program through `strace`?

Comment: Why are you using `goto` instead of a normal `do/while` loop?

Comment: Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as you post only a snippet of code and it is difficult to follow the sample code (no declaration of `sock` is given only a `while` loop without the exact test expression and no complete error checking is done for `poll` system call.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is unconditionally calling `recv()` even when there is no data to read. In fact, you are completely ignoring the `fds.revents` field altogether if `poll()` does not return an error/timeout.

Your loop should look more like this:

```
struct pollfd fds;
fds.fd = sock;
fds.events = POLLIN;

do {
  r = poll(&fds, 1, TIMEOUT*1000);
  if (r == -1) {
    if (errno == EINTR) continue;
    perror("poll() failed");
    break;
  }
  else if (r == 0) {
    printf("timeout expired");
    break;
  }
  else if (fds.revents & POLLIN) {
    r = recv(...);
    if (r < 0) {
      perror("recv() failed");
      break;
    }
    else if (r == 0) {
      printf("socket disconnected\n");
      break;
    }
    else {
      // process data as needed...
    }
  }
  else if (fds.revents & (POLLERR | POLLNVAL)) {
    printf("socket error\n");
    break;
  }
}
while (1);

close(sock);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! I was assuming that setting the `POLLIN` flag in `fds.events`, the return value of `recv` couldn't be 0 because there's always data to be read.